# Работа с Fragment

Tags: android-fragment, android, java

Добрый день. Изучаю android-платформу. Только начал изучать Фрагменты, и возник такой вопрос, возможно, немного глуповатый. У меня два фрагмента, 1-й показывает набор кнопок, нажимая на которые мы должны отобразить какую-либо информацию во 2-м фрагменте. К примеру, есть кнопка "показать  фотографии" и есть кнопка "показать карту GoogleMap". Для фотографий и карт я сверстал в layout-е разметку. Как мне реализовать эти переходы? Как это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно переключиться на другой фрагмент.

```
 Fragment f = new YourFragmnent();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, f);

                ft.commit();

R.id.frame_container - frame layout
```

Answer (score 0):

[Изучайте этот урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html). Конкретно Ваша задача рассматривается в самом конце.

Comment: Не много не то. все учебники кидают из Фрагмента в фрагмент текст, что им отобразить в TextView.а нужно что бы на основании выбранного пункта, загружался нужный Фрагмент с Layout

Comment: Текст кидают для примера, что бы показать механизм взаимодействия. Я не знаю вашей задачи, но я бы сделал несколько фрагментов и переключал их в зависимости от нажатой кнопки в 1м фрагменте. Если это не подходит, то во 2м фрагменте с помощью inflate в подставлял бы разметку необходимого Layout, передавая вместо текста скажем его id.